# Add badge number outlook

Tags: outlook

There is a badge number setting on Android how to get it to show badge number for Outlook on the home screen.

I had assumed this would be pretty standard but does not appear to be.

Tesla Unread fails to work.

Comment: I use Telsa Unread... It works fine. Do you own Nova Launcher Prime? You must own the purchased version of Nova Launcher for Tesla Unread to function.

Comment: @acejavelin for some reason it doesn't work for all badge count set all and unfocused on Oreo on my decide. Badge count works for all apps but outlook consistently for me. Yes I paid for it.

Answer (score 0):

Notyfer it the Play Store seems to work correctly.  Create a notyfer widget with Outlook.

Simply disable foucesed inbox under settings and enable Badge Count->All.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, Display, Home Screen and make sure "App Icon Badges" is enabled.